# ¿Cómo evitar que las direcciones de mi aplicación web en rails se peguen?

Tags: html5, ruby-on-rails

En views por ejemplo tengo en *index.html*:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/">Inicio</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas_estaticas/citas.html">Citas</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas_estaticas/sobre.html">Sobre mi estetica</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas_estaticas/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="paginas_estaticas/contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
    <li>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <p>Bienvenido <%= current_user.email %>   </p>
        <p><%= link_to "Cerrar sesión", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete%></p>
      <%else%>
        <p><%=link_to "Crea una cuenta", new_user_registration_path %></p>
        <p>Si ya tienes cuenta:  <%=link_to "Logueate", new_user_session_path %></p>
      <%end%>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: error]

Comment: ¿con pegarse te refieres a que no las encuentra? ¿Donde tienes guardadas esas páginas estáticas? ¿en la carpeta `/public`? ¿como las tienes guardadas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema está en como declaras las rutas dentro de cada link. En tu caso utilizas rutas relativas, pero creo que buscas rutas absolutas; por ejemplo:

```
<a href="paginas_estaticas/sobre.html">Sobre mi estetica</a>
```

Este link agregará `paginas_estaticas/sobre.html` a la dirección actual; por lo tanto, al ya estar en `paginas_estaticas`, obtienes como resultado: `paginas_estaticas/paginas_estaticas/sobre.html`.

Entonces lo que debes hacer es utilizar rutas absolutas, por ejemplo:

```
<a href="/paginas_estaticas/sobre.html">Sobre mi estetica</a>
```

Al agregar `/` al inicio de la ruta, indicas ruta absoluta, así que evitarás que `paginas_estaticas` se repita.

O bien, puedes seguir utilizando rutas relativas pero elimina `paginas_estaticas`; por ejemplo:

```
<a href="sobre.html">Sobre mi estetica</a>
```

Sin embargo, lo recomendado es utilizar los *helpers* de rails, de esta forma rails se encarga de siempre tener la ruta correcta:

```
<%= link_to "Sobre mi estetica", paginas_estaticas_sobre_path %>
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono!

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu proyecto, en el archivo que se encuentra en `config/routes.rb` defines todas tus rutas.

Por ejemplo, para la imagen que muestras con las rutas, podrías haberlas definido de la siguiente forma:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  namespace 'paginas_estaticas' do
    get '/blog', action: 'blog'
    get '/citas', action: 'citas'
    get '/contacto', action: 'contacto'
    get '/sobre', action: 'sobre'
  end
  resources :products, only: [:index]

end
```

Si miras tus rutas, verás una columna llamada **Helper**. Acá se muestran los siguientes helpers:

- `paginas_estaticas_blog_path`
- `paginas_estaticas_citas_path`
- `paginas_estaticas_contacto_path`
- `paginas_estaticas_sobre_path`
- `products_path`

Estos helpers los usarás para crear tus enlaces en la vista. Por ejemplo en tu archivo index.html, en vez de usar:

```
<li>
  <a href="paginas_estaticas/citas.html">Citas</a>
</li>
```

Lo que usarías es un método helper provisto por Rails llamado **link_to**. El mismo HTML de arriba, ahora lo generarías con:

```
<li>
  <%= link_to 'Citas', paginas_estaticas_citas_path %>
</li>
```

Básicamente el método es:

```
link_to 'Texto del enlace a mostrar', helper
```

Para el caso de:

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/">Inicio</a>
```

Puedes usar como helper path uno provisto por Rails llamado **root_path**

```
<%= link_to 'Inicio', root_path %>
```

Para que esto funcione correctamente, deberías poner en tu archivo `config/routes.rb` quién será el encargado de manejar esa ruta.

```
root to: "nombre_controlador#nombre_accion"
```